# Is the fiber product $X\times_Y Z$ locally irreducible when $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are all locally irreducible?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

The space $X$ is called irreducible at $x$ if the stalk $\mathcal{O}_x$ of its structure sheaf is an integral domain.

The space $X$ is called locally irreducible if all points of $X$ are irreducible.

Assume that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are all locally irreducible  complex analytic spaces. Furthermore,
$f:X\to Y$ and $g:Z\to Y$ are two holomorphic maps (morphisms).
**Then is the fiber product $X\times_Y Z$ locally irreducible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take, for instance
$$
X = Y = Z = \mathbb{A}^1
$$
with the maps $X \to Y$ and $Z \to Y$ given by $x \mapsto x^2$ and $z \mapsto z^2$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you.  I am facing some difficulties in verifying this. Could you please provide some hints (or references) on how to compute the structure sheaf of the relevant spaces?

Comment: @LelongWang The product should be (at least set-theoretically) $\{(x,z) : x^2 = z^2 \} \subset \mathbb A^2$, which is the union of two lines. So it is globally reducible, hence it has to be locally reducible in the intersection point $(0,0)$. To obtain zero-divisors look at functions which vanish identically on one line, and have a single zero on the other line.